# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when trying to explode() dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been looking around for a way to pd.exlode() my entire dataframe that contains lists in the fields to break out the lists out into rows of their own.

The typical way of achieving this seems to be doing something like this:

```
df.set_index('Column_Name').apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

Although when I try and do this to my dataframe I receive  this error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Would anyone know why I'd be receiving this error? My pandas version is 1.5.2

Comment: Can you share a small piece (_as text_) of your dataframe `df` ?

Comment: Turning the lists into tuples should do the job. The reason is that tuples are hashable (can be used as dict keys)